# If $V=L$ then $L(\kappa) = H(\kappa)$

Tags: proof-verification, set-theory

I'm working through Kunen (1980 version) and there is an exercise (pg. 180) to prove that under $V=L$, $L(\kappa) = H(\kappa)$ for all infinite cardinals $\kappa$ (where $H(\kappa)=\{x:|\operatorname{trcl}(x)|<\kappa\}).$

I wrote a proof but I suspect it is too simple and something is wrong. The reason I think it is too simple is that the text proves the theorem for the special case where $\kappa$ is regular. This proof seems marginally easier than that one and doesn't use it. Also, it is proven in Kunen's newer edition (2013-Thm II.6.23) and while the proof is similar to mine below, it looks significantly more complicated. Here is the proof I gave:

**Proof.** Kunen's proof of $L(\kappa)\subseteq H(\kappa)$ doesn't depend on the regularity of $\kappa$ (or V=L for that matter) so what is left is $H(\kappa)\subseteq L(\kappa).$ So let $x\in H(\kappa).$ Define $X=\{x\}\cup \operatorname{trcl}(x).$ We have $|X| < \kappa$ by the definition of $H(\kappa).$

We have the following two theorems:

> 1. (VI 3.9 pg 172) There is a finite conjunction $\chi$ of axioms of ZF - P + V=L such that $$ \forall M[(\mbox{$M$ is transitive }\land \chi^M)\to M=L(o(M))]$$ where $o(M) = M\cap \mathbf{Ordinals}$
> 2. (IV 7.11 pg 140) Let $\mathbf{Z}$ be any transitive class and $\phi$ any sentence. Then $$ \forall X\subseteq Z\;[\mbox{$X$ is transitive} \to \\\exists M\;[X\subseteq M \land (\mbox{$M$ is transitive})\land |M|\le \max(|X|,\omega)\land \phi^{\mathbf Z}\leftrightarrow \phi^M ]]$$

I apply the second theorem with the $\chi$ from the first theorem, $\mathbf Z = \mathbf V=\mathbf L.$ I use the fact that the $X$ defined above is transitive to get a transitive $M$ such that $X\subseteq M,$ $|M| = |X|,$ and $\chi^M\leftrightarrow \chi.$

We know $\chi$ holds since we are working in ZF + V=L and $\chi$ is a conjunction of those axioms. So $\chi^M$ holds. Then, using this and the fact that $M$ is transitive in the first theorem above, we have $M=L(o(M)),$ so $x\in X\subseteq L(o(M))$ which means $x\in L(o(M)).$ Lastly, $|M| = |X| < \kappa,$ so $o(M) < |X|^+ \le \kappa,$ and thus $x\in L(o(M))\subseteq L(\kappa).\; \Box$

My question is whether this proof is correct or I've missed something. I largely did it by modifying the proof of Thm 4.6 that under V = L, $\mathcal P(L(\alpha))\subseteq L(\alpha^+),$ so it seems a little strange that he did the regular $\kappa$ case separately when this argument was available. Between that and the fact that the proof for arbitrary cardinal $\kappa$ in the newer edition  is more complicated even though it seems to be, at its core, a similar reflection argument.

**Edit.**
Looking at the argument in the 2013 edition a little more closely I see that there is actually a quite easy extension from regular cardinals to all cardinals. If it's true for every regular cardinal, it is true for every successor cardinal, so then we have $H(\kappa) = \bigcup_{\lambda<\kappa}H(\lambda^+)=\bigcup_{\lambda<\kappa}L(\lambda^+) = L(\kappa)$ for any limit cardinal $\kappa.$ So perhaps this is what he was going for. Still, the fact that his reflection argument separates the limit and successor cases gives me pause since I didn't need to do that, so still not confident I haven't missed something.

Comment: I don't see how your proof is really different from the original (1980) proof, except that you merged two lemmas together (one of which is used to prove GCH in L).

Comment: And actually I find the proof a bit overcomplicated. I would simply take an elementary submodel of some large $L(\alpha)$, collapse it and use a condensation lemma. Using a metatheoretic global reflection principle feels a bit overkill.

Comment: @Jonathan By the 1980 proof do you mean his proof of 4.11 combined with the extension mentioned in my edit? It seemed superficially different to me but being that it uses the GCH result I can see how it might amount to pretty much the same thing when all the arguments are unrolled. (And Kunen uses the global reflection to do the GCH... would you consider that overkill as well? I think you could do that as well by going to the $L(\alpha)$ that contains $x$ and then to the collapse of an elementary sub model of the appropriate cardinality.)

Comment: @Jonathan I was just a little worried that I saw no need to separate regular from singular cardinals in the proof whereas it is done in both of Kunen’s versions. I was wondering if accidentally used regularity of $\kappa$ somewhere or if using the global reflection instead of the reflection argument in 2013 Kunen somehow allowed me to avoid it (or maybe Kunen didn’t actually need it.)

Comment: I think the difference is that he takes a model which only contains $\operatorname{trcl}(x)$. So whenever $\kappa$ is singular and $\operatorname{trcl}(x) \subseteq L(\kappa)$, although $\vert \operatorname{trcl}(x) \vert < \kappa$, $ \operatorname{trcl}(x)$ could be "unbounded" in $L(\kappa)$. You simply take $\operatorname{trcl}(x) \cup \{ x\}$ directly and then it makes no difference.

Comment: @Jonathan That makes sense. Though it seems he uses $trcl(\{x\})$ in the new version (so I think he unnecessarily split things up, but this is minutiae within something I was already overthinking). Thanks for helping me get a handle on it.